# Setting overwrite for subdomain paths

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, relative-path

I have a website and I decided to add a sub-domain:

```
http://subdomain.dommain.com
```

However, when I created subdomain I chose Document root as: public_html/subdomain to make it easier to include files located there, such as header and footer, for example. Indeed, using a relative path I was able to include them with ease, but my header had some references to CSS and JS files that do not load when I access my sub-domain.

On top of it, I have some overwrite rules in .htaccess file that simplify some inclusions. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /include/assets/account/css/$1 [NC,L]
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Question isn't very clear. Can you please try to explain a bit more? Open your site in FIrebug and see which URLs are not loading and causing 404.

Comment: When I view source from my subdomain my CSS file path is: <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">, however if I click that link (in FireFox) I get to 404 Not Found error page with the following address: http://subdomain.dommain.com/css/style.css, which of course is correct because the actual file is residing at: http://dommain.com/css/style.css

Comment: In that case your current rewrite rule looks culprit. Can you try commenting it?

Comment: Well... it's an established site and I'd rather not touch the path setup. Subdomain is a new addition so i need to figure out this one. Perhaps I can add an .htaccess file to that subdomain and have some custom rewrite rules there...

Comment: Ok, Above .htaccess rule you posted, is it DOCUMENT_ROOT of main site or in DOCUMENT_ROOT of subdomain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using  [HTML BASE tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

For ex is your images base path is `http://domain.com/css/` then put this snippet in `HEAD` section of your page:

```
<base href="http://domain.com/css/">
```